# Is there a way to snake a wire through a pitched ceiling with only 2 holes?

Tags: wiring

I'm in the middle of a second floor bathroom remodel (down to the studs) and I have been using this opportunity to install outlets, ethernet, phone (from a VoIP modem), and coax (for an attic antenna). While I was working, one of the smoke detector's batteries started dying and I realized I should also take this opportunity to install wired smoke detectors too. It seems like one needs its batteries replaced every month or 2.

I have a plan/access to wire the ones in the basement, first, and second floors, but I have no idea how to snake a line through the pitched ceiling of the partially finished attic (which my wife uses as an artist studio).

The attic has no interior walls. The ceiling is about a 45 degree pitch starting from 2 or 3 feet from the floor. There are 3 dormers. There is a single ceiling light. Walls and ceiling are plaster/lath. The house was built in 1920. It's an American Foursquare.

Ideally the detector would go in the center of the room (where the battery one is currently), but I could put it elsewhere.

I could possibly tap into the power from the ceiling light near the current detector, but that wire is likely a 14/2 and the smoke detectors use a 14/3 (to talk to one another). Maybe there exist wired smoke detectors that talk to one another via RF?

If there is no way around opening up the ceiling in multiple places, I may just install a box under the attic floor (going to the second floor detector) so I can tap into that and open up the ceiling to do a full install at a later date. I'm just hoping someone knows a trick.

Comment: Pull a new cable using the old one. Don’t mess up. I would make a really good join between old and new - strong and slim.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I bet that ceiling light is fed off one of the 2 pre-existing outlets in the attic. I'd have to run a wire all the way across the attic floor to get to it though. Ugh.